# Why am I getting this blue border or outline on IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

[image]

I have tried

```
*:focus {
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
  border: 0;
}
* {
  outline: 0; /* also tried outline: none; */
  border: 0;
}
```

This is very annoying, everything I clicked will show this blue border on IE. How can I disabled it? Help!!

Comment: f12>DOM Explorer tab, use the Find tool (looks like an arrow pointing at a box) to select the bounding element that has the highlighting... the style rules for that element will be displayed in the rhs panel of dev tools... css rules cascade... probably you have to move your rules up higher in the css file or add the !important directive to the style rule. eg.*.focus{outline:none!important}. Also MSIE browsers can have a userStylesheet. See Internet Options>General tab, Accessibility button. Also the Narrator app (winkey+Enter) will outline elements on web pages when it is active. inclue repos

Comment: Thank you. I have found out the reason. Turns out it's because I previously added some style to :focus.